# How to change the URl Link in my Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript can any body help me out

```
 urls = urls + "stm_aix(\"p3i0\", \"p1i0\", [0, \"" + item.helpLinkDescription + "\", \"\", \"\", -1, -1, 0, \"" + item.helpLink1 + "\", \"_self\", \"\", \"Help Topics\", \"060508icon4.gif\", \"060508icon5.gif\"], 526, 0);";
```

in the place of item.helpLink1   I have to show something like this

```
ShowURL(item.helpLink1);
```

that is I am dynamically generating this helplinks in ShowURL method.

so that I can use this ShowURL method to pass this helpLink.

Can any body help me out how to update my code.

Comment: What does `ShowURL()` does? Please provide more information.

Comment: this is just a method in my Master page, I am dynamically creating all the links to ShowURL method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Here's what I understand so far:

If all you need to do is replace `item.helpLink1` with your new method you can simply drop it in the same place.

```
urls = urls + [...] + ShowURL(item.helpLink1) + [...]
```

Comment: Can I use somethig like thisurls = urls + "stm_aix(\"p3i0\", \"p1i0\", [0, \"" + item.helpLinkDescription + "\", \"\", \"\", -1, -1, 0, \"" + "ShowURL"(" + " item.helpLink1 " + ")" "\", \"_self\", \"\", \"Help Topics\", \"060508icon4.gif\", \"060508icon5.gif\"], 526, 0);";
                //ur

Comment: I am getting Build Errors in SHowRUl? is that something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use javascript's "eval" function which calls the function something like below.

```
 urls = urls + "stm_aix(\"p3i0\", \"p1i0\", [0, \"" + item.helpLinkDescription + "\", \"\", \"\", -1, -1, 0, \"" + eval(ShowURL(item.helpLink1)) + "\", \"_self\", \"\", \"Help Topics\", \"060508icon4.gif\", \"060508icon5.gif\"], 526, 0);";
```

Comment: Then you can directly call the method directly something like : urls = urls + "stm_aix(\"p3i0\", \"p1i0\", [0, \"" + item.helpLinkDescription + "\", \"\", \"\", -1, -1, 0, \"" + ShowURL(item.helpLink1) + "\", \"_self\", \"\", \"Help Topics\", \"060508icon4.gif\", \"060508icon5.gif\"], 526, 0);";